# Will we be able to install, update and remove snap packages in the Ubuntu Softwares?

Tags: software-center, gui, snap, gnome-software

The only way I know to install, remove and update snap packages is to input commands in the terminal, will I be able to do it in Ubuntu Softwares or some other GUI way?

If we can do that, how do we know whether it is snap packages or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll be able to install/remove snaps via Ubuntu Software. That work is in progress, and doesn't seem to have been released to Xenial just yet.

I don't know if Ubuntu Software will indicate if it's a snap or a deb, though.